# Why does an import not always import nested packages?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Why the first code doesn't work while the second does?

First code:

```
import selenium

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
```

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'webdriver'

Second code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: I am curious about this too. I have noticed that iPython Notebook misses things when you import a module, even if you `from module import *`...

Comment: For what it's worth, selenium's `__init__.py` is just `from selenium import selenium`.  It doesn't import anything else.

Comment: @Michael ... so that means one might want to write `from selenium.selenium import selenium` :D

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, not quite - the imported selenium is the class.  That'll raise an error (`ImportError: No module named selenium`)...

Comment: @Michael I just tried it, it works fine for me

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, strange - that doesn't work for me.

Comment: this is the common behaviour one expect if one think in Java packages or C++ namespaces, but Python follows different rules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nested packages are not automatically loaded; not until you import `selenium.webdriver` is it available as an attribute. Importing *just* `selenium` is not enough.

Do this:

```
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
```

*Sometimes* the package itself will import a nested package in the `__init__.py` package initializer; `os` imports `os.path`, so `os.path` is immediately available even if you import just `os`.